# Flexslider carousel, slide width issue

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm using WooTheme's Flexslider script to run a slideshow with a carousel slider as it's navigation but I'm having a strange issue with the carousel in that the slides are all given a width of 0px. If the browser is resized then the slides revert to their correct sizes so it only seems to be on the initial page load.

I checked out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349167/flexslider-slide-width-issue) but none of those solutions fixed the issue for me.

Here is a [sample URL](http://stage.purenine.com/) and below is a selection of the code that I'm running;

jQuery

```
$('#home-carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    prevText: '',
    nextText: '',
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 500,
    itemMargin: 0,
    minItems: items,
    maxItems: items,
    move: 1,
    asNavFor: '#home-slider2'
});
```

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great

Comment: Improper size calculations are usually due to missing/hidden resources. Be sure to call your init function on DOM ready.

Comment: I am having the same issue , did ya solved it?